# Argtypes: uint8_t from C to Python

Tags: python, c, shared-libraries, uint8t

I'm using ctypes to use a C library in my python script.
I have a function in C library that accepts as argtypes uint8_t and was wondering how to invoke it from python.
This is the C function I'm referring to:

```
void indcpa_keypair(uint8_t pk[KYBER_INDCPA_PUBLICKEYBYTES], uint8_t sk[KYBER_INDCPA_SECRETKEYBYTES])
```

My Pithon script where I'm trying to use it is this

```
def key_generation():
out = CDLL('./PQCgenKAT_kem.so')
out.pqcrystals_kyber512_ref_indcpa_keypair.argtypes =  #I don't know
out.pqcrystals_kyber512_ref_indcpa_keypair.restype = None

pk = [] * CRYPTO_PUBLICKEYBITES
sk = [] * CRYPTO_SECRETKEYBITES
ret_val = out.pqcrystals_kyber512_ref_indcpa_keypair(pk,sk)

couple = [] * 2
couple.insert(0,pk)
couple.insert(1,sk)

if  ret_val != 0 :
    print("ERROR")

return couple
```

I don't know if it seems clear what this method have to do. If you have any doubts, feel free to comment so I can solve the problem and learn something new.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you use https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html, you probably want `c_ubyte`

Comment: Thanks for the comment! So if I understand correctly I have to use `c_ubyte` as argtypes. But if I then try to pass two lists (as in the script above) it gives me this error:  
`ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type`

Comment: looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72189109/init-from-ctypes-constructor/72190531#72190531) I suspect you may be wanting the c_uint8 object, however you may also need to create an array of these to match the size you are putting in (such as below...or similar)

`InputType1 = (ctypes.c_int * CRYPTO_PUBLICKEYBITES)()`

You may also want to check your function name as it should match the compiled c function `indcpa_keypair()` I think, you can check this by running `nm` on the library.

Comment: Thanks @liamcsmith! I solved it this way I am also attaching the link to the code that helped me solve the problem [link](https://gist.github.com/lmammino/10ae9ad290809f172e6eb3b6957bd18c)