# __init__ from ctypes constructor

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have a C struct and a constructor

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t index;
    int32_t line;
    int16_t column;
} Position;

Position positionCreate() {
    Position position;
    position.index = 0;
    position.line = -1;
    position.column = -1;
    return position;
}
```

That has a Python class equivalent

```py
from ctypes import *


library = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libposition.so')


class Position(Structure):

    _fields_ = [
        ('index', c_uint32),
        ('line', c_int32),
        ('column', c_int16),
    ]
```

When I initialize the class "manually":

```
constructor = library.positionCreate
constructor.restype = Position
position = constructor()
print(position.index, position.line, position.column)
```

I get the desired output:

> `0, -1, -1`

But I want to use this constructor:

```
class Position(Structure):

    _fields_ = [
        ('index', c_uint32),
        ('line', c_int32),
        ('column', c_int16),
    ]

    def __init__(self):

        # Or words to this effect
        self = library.positionCreate()
```

And when I try this:

```
position = Position()
print(position.index, position.line, position.column)
```

I no longer get the right output:

> `0, 0, 0`

I think my syntax of `self = positionCreate()` is wrong, but I don't know what would be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` can't be assigned like that.  What you need is `__new__`, which can return an instance of the class like you want:

test.c

```c
#include <stdint.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

typedef struct {
    uint32_t index;
    int32_t line;
    int16_t column;
} Position;

API Position positionCreate() {
    Position position;
    position.index = 0;
    position.line = -1;
    position.column = -1;
    return position;
}
```

test.py

```py
from ctypes import *

class Position(Structure):

    _fields_ = [('index', c_uint32),
                ('line', c_int32),
                ('column', c_int16)]

    def __new__(cls):
        return dll.positionCreate()

dll = CDLL('./test')
dll.positionCreate.argtypes = ()
dll.positionCreate.restype = Position

position = Position()
print(position.index, position.line, position.column)
```

Output:

```
0 -1 -1
```

Comment: Can you explain the preprocessor block at the top of your answer? What does it do?

Comment: @InigoSelwood I'm on Windows using Visual Studio, and it requires explicitly exporting functions with `__declspec(dllexport)`, but that's not supported by other compilers.  It makes the code useable as as for others.